# Miroservices interservice communication with Sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, network-programming, microservices

I'm currently designing a system for the following scenario:
Data is streamed from a client, being processes by multiple services one after the other (no parallel). Then, the data is streamed back to the client while it's being analyzed. It's important that the server will return to the client partial analyzed data during the process (That's why I need sockets).

The client can even send more information during the analyze on the server and it may impact the analysis results.

[A high level sketch I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS4bp.png)

I have made a lot of research into this, and I have seen only **REST microservices** OR async processing with sockets using all kinds of **messaging queues**. 
I have not seen anyone who implements microservices with so many opened sockets directly between the services.

Now for my question:
Am I doing the right thing here? Is opening sockets between all of my servers is wrong or unreliable?

Comment: Which OS are you going to use?

Comment: Probably Docker over Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so I'll try to give you a few broad thoughts on this:

First of all, I think that the general idea is perfectly fine. All microservices use sockets one way or the other you're just taking it to a lower level without the various abstractions on top. That makes sense especially if you have some very specific requirements.

The number of sockets doesn't seem that large to me. I've seen systems maintain thousands of concurrent open sockets **ten years ago**. What you're suggesting seems trivial on modern hardware and operating systems.

So overall, the design is **totally doable**. But the problem is that you'll be forced to re-invent some wheels along the way. I'll mention a few of them.

First, you'd need **service discovery** for the microservices to find each other.

Then you'd need to design a protocol between each pair of services - you'd need to specify messages and rules for when and how to send them. You'd need message builders and parsers; as well as logic for handling various message errors, and forward/backward compatibility. This is trickier than it sounds, especially if the communication has to be robust. This brings me to the next point - handling network failures.

What network failures? TCP is reliable, right? Well, not entirely. First, there are the disconnections and various network errors. Then, there are some quiet failures - Try opening a socket to a remote machine, then *suddenly* pulling its network cable. How long will it take for the local socket to throw an exception? Well, it turns out that it could take **minutes**, minutes during which you local socket thinks that the remove machine is alive and well. Sure, if data arrives, then it arrives without error and in the right order. But that's only **if** it arrives.

Then there's the threading. While not unique to pure sockets, threading tends to be more painful on lower abstraction levels.

So while it can be done, you might want to try to avoid re-inventing some of the wheels here. For instance, how about using an [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) library? They exist for all modern languages, and the already solve some of the problems you'll have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation Malt! I have learned from it. BTW, I am going to use standard libraries over socket to transfer the data (socket.io or others)